# Extract JSON from JS Module in WebPack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

I have Javascript file that contains a list of datasets. Each dataset has an image attached to it.

```
const placeholderThumb = new URL("images/placeholder.png?width=450?as=webp", import.meta.url)
const placeholder = new URL("images/placeholder.png?width=450?as=webp", import.meta.url)
export default [{
  "id": "universum",
   ....
  "thumbnail": new URL("images/universum.jpg?width=450&as=webp", import.meta.url),
  "images": [
    new URL("images/universum.jpg?width=750&as=webp", import.meta.url)
  ]
 }, {
  "id": "studcad",
  ....
  "thumbnail": placeholderThumb,
  "images": [
    placeholder
   ]
 },
...
```

I use ImageMinimizerPlugin as minimizer for those images. Everything is working fine when I include the module via a normal js `import` in my app.

Now I want webpack to output / serialize that data in a secondary JSON file to make the list processable by different systems. The resulting JSON should include the image urls resolved by the ImageMinimizerPlugin loader.

Is there a way in webpack to accomplish this?